# i want TimerTask pause and resume

Tags: android

i am working in a game so i have need to use time which update in every second.i am using TimerTask.I want to pause time When i clicked on a button and want to resume it again when i clicked on resume button from other activity.How to do it please help me.

```
t=new Timer();
{
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
{
public void run()
{
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() 
{
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
tv.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d",minute,seconds));

time += 1;
seconds += 1;
if(seconds==60)
{
seconds=0;
}
minute=time/60;
}

                    });
                }
            }, 0, 1000);

        }
```

Comment: `cancel()` the Timer, create a new one and start it when you Resume.

Comment: don't use a Timer at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this this is what You want
just copy and paste


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText t;
    Button b;
    Button b2;
    Timer timer;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        t=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_dark);
        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask updateProfile = new CustomTimerTask(MainActivity.this);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateProfile, 0,1000); 
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    timer.cancel();
            }
        });
b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask updateProfile = new CustomTimerTask(MainActivity.this);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateProfile, 0,1000);
            }
        });
    } 

    class CustomTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        private Context context;
        private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        // Write Custom Constructor to pass Context
        public CustomTimerTask(Context con) {
            this.context = con;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Calendar c =Calendar.getInstance(); 
        int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        int min= c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int hour= c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                                t.setText(hour+":"+min+":"+seconds);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are much better off using CountDownTimer. CountDownTimer internally used a Handler and executes callbacks on the UI (main thread). This allows to make your code cleaner.

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(1000000, 1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
timer.start();
```

Now you need to pass a reference to it from one Activity to another. I think the most common, simple and ugly way is to have a static resolver class.

```
public class CountDownTimer {
    private static Alarms sCountDownTimer;

    public static CountDownTimer getCountDownTimer () {
        if (sCountDownTimer  == null) throw new NullPointerException("CountDownTimer not initialized yet");
        return sCountDownTimer;
    }

    public static void init(CountDownTimer countDownTimer) {
        if (sCountDownTimer  == null) {
            sCountDownTimer  = countDownTimer;
        } else throw new RuntimeException("Attept to reinitialize!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are much better posting things to the UI thread, delayed.  You want something like:

```
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
getMainLooper().postDelayed(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override void run() {
            tv.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d",minute,seconds));
    } },
    60 * 1000)
```